# Better way to set values of list

Tags: python

```
def max_end3(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[0] > nums[2]:
            nums[0] = nums[0]
            nums[1] = nums[0]
            nums[2] = nums[0]
            return nums
        elif nums[2] > nums[0]:
            nums[0] = nums[2]
            nums[1] = nums[2]
            nums[2] = nums[2]
            return nums
        elif nums[0] == nums[2]:
            nums[0] = nums[0]
            nums[1] = nums[0]
            nums[2] = nums[0]
            return nums
```

The task was to replace all items of a list with either the first or last index depending on which is greater. I got the answer correct but is there a shorter and more efficient way of writing this code?

Comment: Are your trying to sort the array of numbers? If so, I suggest you to think about making this simpler yourself. Because these the basics of learning programming. If you take help, you may lose it. If you still fail, then post additional code that you attempted, then I will help. Otherwise, there is a built-in function called `sort()`.

Comment: If you are sorting array, learn how may types of sort techniques are there. To start with, Look for Bubble sort, Binary sort, etc. Then you will learn the logic.

Comment: The OP is not trying to sort the list.

Comment: Is it intentional that the first and last cases do exactly the same thing?  You could just use `>=` instead of having two separate tests. In any case, your return statement means you never do more than one iteration, making the loop unnecessary (aside from the fact that you never actually use the value of `i` in even the first iteration).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got repeated logic.  That is, in each of the three `if` clause blocks, you're setting all three locations equal to a particular value and then returning `nums`.  Furthermore, you're using an `if` block to determine which of the two values is larger.  The built-in function `max` will do this for you.  So,

```py
def max_end3(nums):
    max_value = max(nums[0], nums[2])
    for i in range(3):
        nums[i] = max_value
    return nums
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on your code, you only really need to return a list of len(nums) numbers, of value max(nums):

```
def max_end3(nums):
    return [max(nums[0], nums[-1])]*len(nums)
```

Comment: It's not clear if this is what the OP needs but notice that, originally, `nums` itself was being modified returned.  Here, you're returning a new object.

Comment: Very true, but then I guess you wouldn't need a return statement in your answer right ?

Comment: That depends on how the function is being used.